# tiled map collision in Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, phaser-framework

I am using Phaser 2.1.3. I create a tiled map with Tiled 0.9.1
There is only one defualt layer, and one tileset image(4 colr tiles 32x32).
[image]

I want to make the orange tile solid, player can't go through this kind of tile.

But in my game, the player can't go through orange tiles block neither red tiles block on stage. I don't why red tile block is solid.

This is some of my code, full code here: https://github.com/q...sets/js/game.js

```
var map = this.add.tilemap('map1');
map.addTilesetImage('tileset');
map.setCollisionByExclusion([1]); // set orange tile solid
this.layer1 = map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1');
this.layer1.resizeWorld();
map.setTileIndexCallback(4, this.reachedDoorEvent, this); // when player reached black block, reachedDoorEvent function will invoke.
```

You can test it here: http://qichunren.github.io/game1/index.html move the player(candy) by arrow keys.

Is a phaser bug or did I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `map.setCollisionByExclusion`. From the docs:

"Sets collision on all tiles in the given layer, **except for the IDs of those in the given array**. The 'collides' parameter controls if collision will be enabled (true) or disabled (false)."

(emphasis mine)

If you want just the orange tile solid you should use `map.setCollision`.

Comment: I wrongly thought the tile id is index of a tileset. I now get to know tile id is from layers data key in tile json file.